# Using a View in a DBContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have recently implemented an MVC3 website and had to now include data from a view.
As Shown below I went about setting it up much like I would a table then I got the below error.
I am unsure of how to set this up .
I have provided some of the classes below to help point me in the right direction.

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>     System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'AJF_ProfitCentres' has no key defined. 
>   Define the key for this EntityType.
>     System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: 
>   EntitySet �ProfitCentres� is based on type 
>   �AJF_ProfitCentres� that has no keys

```
public class NavContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AJF_ProfitCentres> ProfitCentres { get; set; }

    public NavContext()
        : base("NavContext")
    {
    }
}


public class NavRepository : INavRepository
{
    private readonly NavContext _context;

    public NavRepository(NavContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<AJF_ProfitCentres> GetAllProfitCentres()
    {
        return _context.ProfitCentres.ToList();
    }
 }


     public class AJF_ProfitCentres
{
    public int ProfitCentreId;
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "ProfitCentre cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
    public string ProfitCentre { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(64, ErrorMessage = "AccountId cannot be longer than 64 characters.")]
    public string AccountId { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Okay. the problem here is I am using code first and sql views. I think I'll just rewrite the code to use the underlying tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a followup I ended up creating it as a seperate datacontext built from the view rather than code first works like a dream.